# How to set different expiry times for different documents in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So far in all the code samples I have seen on how to create self destructing documents in Mongodb the `expireAt` field is usually always constant as shown below

```
new TokenSchema({token:String, type:String, createdAt: { type: Date, expires: 3600 }});
```

Is there no way to make this expires field value computed dynamically? Such that I can have:

```
let newToken = new Token({
   token,
   type,
   expires: getTimeToDestroy() //Computed programmatically
});
newToken.save();
```

The reason been that I don't want all tokens to expire after 3600s, I want some to expire after a programmatically computed amount of seconds depending on the token type.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Set `expires: 0` and put the desired date into that field. I am not familiar with mongoose, could be like this:

```
new TokenSchema({token:String, type:String, destroyAt: { type: Date, expires: 0 }});
```

See [Expire Documents at a Specific Clock Time](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time)